# Converting Milliseconds to Date returns 1970 as year

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

```
long mil = new Date().getTime();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(mil);
System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Above code is returning **1970-01-02 21:57:09**. What is the problem?

It's not working in Android.

Comment: Where is the problem? The code does what you have intructed to do.

Comment: Check your system time.

Comment: You could add a line to print out `mil` to see what the unformatted system time is.

Comment: What pauli said, print mil and also System.currentTimeMillis() and compare them

Comment: @Michael-O You see, year is 1970.

Comment: i checked in eclipse output is 2013-04-09 18:27:15.may check ur locale or current system time

Comment: Dont really see what difference doing this in Android will have. This should work fine as you have it. do a `system.out.println` on the value in `mil` and let us know what value it is...

Comment: I don’t know the answer. But getting a wrong date-time value in the year 1970 is usually a sign of using seconds where milliseconds was expected. The beginning of 1970 is the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it?..Can't u simply do this?:

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat.....
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do can be achieved by a simple method:

```
Date currentDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("Formatted date time::: " +formatter.format(currentDate));
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can use the Joda-Time library on Android. The code is more simple and more clear.

```
System.out.println( DateTime.now() );
```

When run…

```
2014-02-03T04:05:06.789Z
```